# How can I get Oracle ODP to work with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle11g

I have been trying for several hours to try and get the Oracle 11g ODP Driver to work with ASP.NET MVC 3 with .NET Framework 4.0.  All projects in my solution are set to AnyCPU and .NET Framework 4.0.  I have a set of NUNIT integration tests that are able to use the driver and it runs fine.  However I am unable to get my MVC web project to work with the ODP driver.

I get this error in my Visual Studio 2010 development environment on a 64bit machine when I try to run the web project and call the TestConnection:

*Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

I get this error on my 64 Bit Dev Server:

*Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.*

Here is my connection string in the web config:

```
<add name ="POMSNETDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myService)));User Id=xxxx;Password=yyyy;" />
```

Here is my code to connect:

```
public class Repository
{
    public void TestConnection()
    {
        OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POMSNETDatabase"].ToString());
        myConnection.Open();
    }
}
```

I have verified that I have both Oracle.DataAccess.dll and OraOps11w.dll in my bin directory.

Comment: Have you installed ODP on your dev server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities to get it working:

1. Check if the references if the `Oracle.DataAccess` is marked to Copy local.
2. Compile your main application in 32 bits. (web project).
3. On the IIS, configure the application pool executing in 32 bits.
4. On the IIS, configure the application pool to execute using `Local System`.

I had some problems with Odp provider, it does not execute in 64 bits servers for me, I have to apply it using 32 bits on application pool.

Comment: Okay, the problem was that I am using Visual Studio 2010.  While the unit tests, execute in either 32/64 bit mode, Casini only executes in 32 bit mode.  You can compile http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/ into 64 bit and it works.  See the documentation there on where to install.